# Protocol for Web Service (Real-time)

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, web-services, real-time

I'm a little bit confused on what approach is best in this situation. So I am in the process of building a web service in Ruby on Rails. The framework is kinda irrelevant but I added that detail anyways. The web service is based upon a real-time model

I'm currently leaning on Java to process the real-time data, especially for the notifications.   So this is either going to be comet or web socket based web service. (Leaning on comet)

My question is: What kind of protocol should I use to access the Java server?

I've read that http might be too heavy for a notification / real-time setup and some people recommend a pure UDP protocol. Is this correct?

Let me know if you need me to clarify on anything!

EDIT:

The number of notifications is going to be significant for each user. Since notifications will  also be related to tips about their account (Can't really say much more than that). I want to be able to account for 5,000 - 10,000 users all having hundreds of notifications each week. Real-time for notifications "can" have a lag, but I'm trying to get as little as possible. The size of the messages will not be very big. About the same size as a typical notification, so a few lines of text, the user id, etc...

Comment: you sure you want to try to glue together all those different languages?  seems a bit extreme for a "green field" project...

Comment: Left out the C++ and all that algorithm stuff since it's gonna be separated from this particular web service.

Comment: probably should provide more details on the expected size of messages, number of messages, speed requirements (aka how "real time")...

Comment: again, to clarify, you are asking about the communication layer between the java processing backend and your ruby webservice frontend?  not server to many client communication, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for 10k users with 100 messages a week, that works out to about 1.5 messages a second.  not network shattering.  seeing as you control the servers on both ends, i'm not sure why you are contemplating http or webservices.  just open a socket connection between the servers and send the messages as necessary.